# How to create a new contact into a group directly using Google contacts API?

Tags: json, api, google-contacts-api

When I create a contact, it gets created in the "My contacts" list. But I need to add a contact directly inside a group/folder.

So,on the whole
 - I'm able to create a group using People API.
 - I'm able to create a new contact (it gets added into Mycontacts/all
   list ) and move it to the desired group.

But, not able to create inside a group.

IMAGE LINKS

- Getting the list of groups (Group named "Testing") [Groups list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Id4.png)
- Trying to create a new contact using "resource name" of "testing"
  [Contact creating...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4vjO.png)
- The contact should get added to the folder "testing 2", instead it
  directly gets added to "mycontacts": [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cllDN.png)

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita 
My Apologies.  I'm not able to add an image from my account. Please check the link if needed.